# Angular adds 'bearer' string to authentication header after build

Tags: angular, jwt, passport.js

On my back-end (Nodejs + Express) I have protected routes with JWT token. In development environment, HTTP Authorization header in request looks like this:

```
Authorization: JWT token_string
```

After I build angular app, built app for some reason adds 'Bearer ' in header:

```
Authorization: Bearer JWT token_string
```

Request:

```js
 addTemplate(template: ITemplate): Observable<ISuccessMsgResponse> {
    return this.http.post<ISuccessMsgResponse>(`${this.ULR}template`, template, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Authorization': this.token.getToken()
      })
    });
  }
```

Node:

```
.post(passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), (req, res) => {
     // Code to execute
}
```

passport:

```
module.exports = function(passport) {
    let opts = {};
    opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('jwt');
    opts.secretOrKey = config.secret;
    passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, (jwtPayload, done) => {
        User.getUserById(jwtPayload._id, (err, user) => {
            if(err) {
                return done(err, false)
            }
            if(user) {
                return done(null, user)
            } else {
                return done(null, false)
            }
        })
    }))
}
```

If I try doing request with the same Authorization header format as in development, everything works fine. So the problem is in the built version of Angular, which adds 'Bearer ' in Authorization header. Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is half year later but still, just wanting to post the answer to my problem.
The problem in this case was that in development, `HttpClient` didn't append 'Bearer' string in the start of 'Authorization' header, but in the production it was included.
Development: `JWT token_string`
Production: `Bearer JWT token_string`
The solution was quite annoying, because I had to manually find the part in built script where Authorization Header was and remove 'JWT' in string, where the header is being set, since it looks like Bearer is required to be in it.

Before: `Bearer JWT token_string`
After: `Bearer token_string`

In the backend, string for extraction also had to be modified.
Before:

```js
    let opts = {};
    opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('jwt');
    opts.secretOrKey = config.secret;
    passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, (jwtPayload, done) => {
        User.findById(jwtPayload._id, (err, user) => {
            if(err) {
                return done(err, false);
            }
            if(user) {
                return done(null, user);
            } else {
                return done(null, false);
            }
        });
    }));
```

After:

```js
    let opts = {};
    opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('bearer');
    opts.secretOrKey = config.secret;
    passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, (jwtPayload, done) => {
        User.findById(jwtPayload._id, (err, user) => {
            if(err) {
                return done(err, false);
            }
            if(user) {
                return done(null, user);
            } else {
                return done(null, false);
            }
        });
    }));
```

I'm not export in this topic, but I really don't see reason why 'Bearer' wouldn't be added in development like in production. Might just be a bug (Angular 7). IDK.

Comment: @SaadAbbasi ill try, go ahead

Answer (score 1):

It's quite a time from last answer but it might be helpful to someone - and prevent some pain, like mine until I came up with a 'solution'.

In short, the request is:

```
getUserProfile(){
this.loadCurrentToken();
const headers = new HttpHeaders({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  Authorization: this.authToken,
});
console.log(headers);
return this.http.get('/users/profile', {headers});
}
```

The problem I faced was that while at development mode (ng serve) the token produced at the Authorization Header was of the form: **JWT eyfhik4u5h4tb**...etc, in the production mode (ng build --prod), the 'Bearer' word was added as prefix so now the token was: **Bearer JWT eyfhik4u5h4tb**...etc (just like the above answer suggests)

Of course this is the standard but also didn't want to change to extraction method from the **fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('jwt')** method, meaning this:

```
let opts ={};
opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('jwt');
opts.secretOrKey = config.secret;
passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done) => {
    User.getUserById(jwt_payload._id, (err, user) => {
        if(err){
            return done(err, false);
        }

        if(user){
           return done(null, user); 
        } else {
            return done(null, false);
        }
    });
}));
```

...to something else, let's say **fromAuthHeaderWithScheme(auth_scheme)** or **fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken()** and continue with the respective changes.

So, what I did, and as far is working great both in production and development mode was to  try and get a 'clean' token - in the form of **JWT eyfhik4u5h4tb**...etc in either environment, both dev & prod.

My approach was to modify the **//node_modules/passport-jwt/lib/auth_headers.js** file as such:

```
'use strict';

var re = /(\S+)\s+(\S+)/;



function parseAuthHeader(hdrValue) {
    if (typeof hdrValue !== 'string') {
        return null;
    }

    /* ADDED THIS LINE */
    hdrValue = hdrValue.substring(hdrValue.indexOf('JWT') + 0);
    /* --------------- */

    var matches = hdrValue.match(re);
    // console.log(hdrValue);
    return matches && { scheme: matches[1], value: matches[2] };
}



module.exports = {
    parse: parseAuthHeader
};
```

So, now, the extractor will care only for the portion of the token that starts with JWT and ignores the Bearer prefix - or whatever one - if present.

Something that one should keep in mind of course, with this approach, is that when deploying the application, should include the specific, changed, passport-jwt module because upon npm-install the module will reinitiate/update etc and won't work.